# Adding commas to Django for loop values

Tags: javascript, html, django, for-loop

I am trying to write a javascript to 3 digit comma separate number values that are passed in through my django database and can't figure it out. Exp: (1000 -> 1,000). Before writing the JS, I am also trying to figure out if I comma separate these values, will they mess up potential usage in other JS code that utilize these numbers to do math? Thanks.

```
    <table class="database-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Market Value</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for s in securities %}
                        <tr>
                            <td id="security-value">${{s.market_value_of_security}}</td>
                        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
      const security_value = document.getElementById("security-value");


      function numberWithCommas(x) {
         return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django templates you can use the `intcomma` templatetag to add thousands commas:
`${{ s.market_value_of_security|intcomma }}`

Then in javascript, you can first use `replace` to remove the spaces, commas and $ from the string and then convert the number string into an actual number with `parseFloat`:
`number = parseFloat(numberText.replace(/[ ,$]/g, ""))`